# How to remove side bar of best seller in my account page of Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, blocks, sidebar, account-dashboard

I want to remove sidebar of best seller in My account page of magento 2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Copy **customer_account.xml** into your Theme

```
     <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
```

**If not resolved it then please find block or container name to display it.**

Comment: 1+ if answer was correct or satisfy with answer please aapprov answer.

Comment: most welcome bro..happy coding..:)